# How to remove an element's content with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Say I have a div and some content inside it.

```
<div>
      Content
</div>
```

With JQuery, how do I empty the div without removing the div, only the content inside?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the [empty](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/empty) function to remove all the child nodes (all its content) of an element:

```
$('#elementId').empty();
```

The empty function will also remove all the event handlers and the jQuery internally cached data.

Answer (score 10):

If the div has an id, you can do it like this:

```
$('#id-of-div').html('');
```

Or you can do all classes of .class-of-div

```
$('.class-of-div').html('');
```

Or just all divs

```
$('div').html('');
```

EDIT: But `empty()` (above) would work better.

Comment: Thanks for this other suggestion Dave.

Comment: I think you mean `$('.class-of-div').html('');`

Answer (score 1):

Html

```
<div id='emptythis'>
   Content
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#emptythis').html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "div" ).remove( ".hello" );
```

Similar to `.empty()`, the `.remove()` method takes elements out of the DOM. Use `.remove()` when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed. To remove the elements without removing data and events, use `.detach()` instead.

[reference](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)