# JavaScript/jQuery html(null) vs html('')

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

is there a best way of "clearing" html inside an element using jQuery? I use `.html(null)` but is `.html("")` more efficient. And is there an even better/nicer way of achieving this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove an element's content with JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474607/how-to-remove-an-elements-content-with-jquery)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is there a reason for not just using `.empty()`?

And, incidentally, if your question is about 'efficiency,' so long as efficiency is broadly comparable with speed, then might I suggest [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/) for self-testing?

Incidentally, in a [JS Perf comparison](http://jsperf.com/empty-null-or-empty-string), with Chromium 18/Ubuntu 11.04, `.empty()` seems to be consistently the faster approach.
References:

Further to the above; if you don't mind using plain ol' native JavaScript, it's *even faster* (on my Samsung II the DOM runs at ~82k ops/sec, on my desktop (nothing special) in Chromium 18/Ubuntu 11.04, the DOM runs at: ~860k ops/sec, as opposed to `.empty()` (the next fastest) at 8.4k ops/sec).

A DOM-based approach:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
while (list.firstChild) {
  list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
}
```

[JS Perf comparison of all above approaches](http://jsperf.com/empty-null-or-empty-string/2).

References:

- [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).

Comment: With `null` as value he is using `empty` - indirectly http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.7.1/jQuery.fn.html

Comment: thanks for your reply, do you know if there is an equivalent for setting empty .val()??

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of help =) as to the `val()` question, then no, I don't believe there is, in that case.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

provided by jQuery